# IS there solution for problem of showing undefined in kendo dropdown core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a problem with the kendo dropdown core that returns the undefined result

[image: click to view picture]

[image: click to view picture]

[image: click to view picture]

Comment: Please paste your [code as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the default json serialization options.

Configure the json serialization options in `Startup.cs` as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

Or use camel case in the configuration of the drop down:

```
datatextfield="description"
datavaluefield="communityNo"
```